# Rails Filterrific and saved searches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filterrific

i am trying to implement filterrific in my app, but i am finding it rather difficult. One thing is shortening my sleep and that is saved searches. Does anyone have any pointers on how to implement it.

Best regards,
Luka

Comment: The documentation mentions, that this is possible, bud does not provide instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a Search controller separately to save the search results. Follow the railscasts Advanced search form. It's clear and informative. And I think your final solution would be the mixture of that and Filterrific.